# How to navigate between Tabs in android

Tags: android, tabactivity

I have created a TabActivity in my android application. When user selects the second tab, an alert dialog will appear. Is there any way to navigate to the previous tab when user clicks the cancel button for the dialog box.

regards
dj

---

I found the solution here:

[Android - Switch Tabs from within an Activity within a tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541802/android-switch-tabs-from-within-an-activity-within-a-tab)

In my case, I have used the solution of 'GrandPrix'.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to first know about the Tab Widget:

1. http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html
2. http://www.androidpeople.com/android-tabhost-tutorial-part-1/

You can set the tab using setCurrentTab method:

```
   tab_host.setCurrentTab(2);   // 2nd tab button is showing initially
```

same way, you can set the tab-button on the cancel button.

Comment: Hi, How can I apply this in my code? How to get the current tabhost value to set the tab.

Comment: @Dijo David i have updated my answer, check it out and read and learn about the tabWidget first, then you have a better idea