# Android : how to insert an image in the tab

Tags: android

I have created 3 tabs, i have some text in them however now i need to insert images as well, can anyone help me with this? I have some code in my xml document is this code useful or should i get rid of it

Answer (score 0):

Try tis code for TabActivity:

```
 TabHost  tabHost = getTabHost();
            addTab(this.getString(R.string.tabname),R.drawable.tabimage,ActivityInTab.class);

private void addTab(String title, int imageId, Class<? extends Activity> activity ){
        tabHost.setup(this.getLocalActivityManager());
        TabSpec ts = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab_"+title);
        ts.setIndicator(title,getResources().getDrawable(imageId));
        ts.setContent(new Intent(this, activity));
        tabHost.addTab(ts);        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

[Link to example.](http://www.higherpass.com/Android/Tutorials/Working-With-Images-In-Android/)

Like i said in the [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8648959/writing-text-in-tabs-on-android/8649049#8649049). Take a loot at [ImageView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html). You will need to do some research in this. There are tons of examples on google. Use this as a reference and then try find something that will help you.