# using a button to switch between tabs

Tags: android

Does anyone know how to create a button which will help me to switch between tabs?

```
Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);    
    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  
        public void onClick(View v) {{
            // Perform action on click   
                if (v.getId() == R.id.button1) {
                    setContentView(R.layout.tab3);    
                }
                else if (v.getId() == R.id.button1) {
                    setContentView(R.layout.main);  
                }
            }
        }
    });
}}
```

this is the code in my tab 1,  this next code is the button in my tab.xml. i want to press the buy button below and i want it to go to another tab, is this possible?

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:text="Buy"  
        android:onClick="tab3" />
```

this is my logcat file

```
01-05 16:04:20.903: D/dalvikvm(215): GC freed 806 objects / 70928 bytes in 96ms
01-05 15:30:29.072: D/AndroidRuntime(213): Shutting down VM
01-05 15:30:29.082: W/dalvikvm(213): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
01-05 15:30:29.082: E/AndroidRuntime(213): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
01-05 15:30:29.132: E/AndroidRuntime(213): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method tab3(View) in the activity
01-05 15:30:29.132: E/AndroidRuntime(213):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2020)
01-05 15:30:29.132: E/AndroidRuntime(213):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
01-05 15:30:29.132: E/AndroidRuntime(213):  at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:4179)
01-05 15:30:29.132: E/AndroidRuntime(213):  at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:6541)
01-05 15:30:29.132: E/AndroidRuntime(213):  at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3709)
01-05 16:04:25.693: E/AndroidRuntime(215):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
01-05 16:04:25.693: E/AndroidRuntime(215):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
01-05 16:04:25.693: E/AndroidRuntime(215):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
01-05 16:04:25.693: E/AndroidRuntime(215):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
01-05 16:04:25.693: E/AndroidRuntime(215):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
01-05 16:04:25.693: E/AndroidRuntime(215):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
01-05 16:04:25.693: E/AndroidRuntime(215):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
01-05 16:04:25.693: E/AndroidRuntime(215):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
01-05 16:04:25.693: E/AndroidRuntime(215):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1659)
01-05 16:04:25.693: E/AndroidRuntime(215):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
01-05 16:04:25.693: E/AndroidRuntime(215):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2061)
01-05 16:04:25.693: E/AndroidRuntime(215):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)
01-05 16:04:25.693: E/AndroidRuntime(215):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1691)
01-05 16:04:25.693: E/AndroidRuntime(215):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-05 16:04:25.693: E/AndroidRuntime(215):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-05 16:04:25.693: E/AndroidRuntime(215):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
01-05 16:04:25.693: E/AndroidRuntime(215):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-05 16:04:25.693: E/AndroidRuntime(215):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-05 16:04:25.693: E/AndroidRuntime(215):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
01-05 16:04:25.693: E/AndroidRuntime(215):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
01-05 16:04:25.693: E/AndroidRuntime(215):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-05 16:04:25.693: E/AndroidRuntime(215): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Tab3
01-05 16:04:25.693: E/AndroidRuntime(215):  at java.lang.ClassCache.findMethodByName(ClassCache.java:308)
01-05 16:04:25.693: E/AndroidRuntime(215):  at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1014)
01-05 16:04:25.693: E/AndroidRuntime(215):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2017)
01-05 16:04:25.693: E/AndroidRuntime(215):  ... 25 more
01-05 16:04:25.733: I/dalvikvm(215): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
01-05 16:04:25.733: I/dalvikvm(215): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
01-05 16:04:27.505: I/Process(215): Sending signal. PID: 215 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 5):

+1 Midoalageb and +1 Mark Gjol have given you exactly what you need to switch the tab. What they are leaving out is the code for the event you are trying to do. What you need to do is set up a button on `TAB1` that will have an `onClick()` listener that will call either `getTabHost().setCurrentTabByTag(TAB2);` or `getTabHost().setCurrentTab(1);`. Either one of those will work fine, just depends on how you want to do it.

Do you know how to do buttons and `onClick()` listeners? If not, google has some great examples. Just create a button in your tabView then set the onClick and then put your code in there for switching to the tab you want.

[Another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541802/android-switch-tabs-from-within-an-activity-within-a-tab) that is very similar to this one that may help you out.

---

getTabHost().setCurrentTabByTag(TAB2);

This will look for the tab labeled "TAB2" and change to that tab.

---

getTabHost().setCurrentTab(1);

This will look for the tab with the index of "1" and change to that tab.

---

**In regards to your xml**

The xml files are mainly used to abstract defining your Views from the implementation of your Views. This allows you or other developers to provide different views to your code if needed. It helps provide a way to use the [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) pattern. However, this pattern is a little different in Android, but the xml file is most commonly considered the View in that pattern.

**So Yes**, if you are going to have multiple buttons they will need to be defined in your xml and implemented in your code.

---

**In regards to your button dilema**

The [API for Button from google](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html) actually provides you with an example of this on the very front page. Keep in mind that Android is maturing very fast as a development platform and A LOT of this stuff is actually well documented already on line. The API documentation is also very good and gives great examples. Go by there and read it and you will most likely solve a lot of the more easy problems there.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    TextView textview = new TextView(this);
    textview.setText("This is Tab1");
    setContentView(textview);

    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Perform action on click
            // perform the switch to tab event here for instance...
            getTabHost().setCurrentTabByTag("TAB2");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: that is all the code i have in my xml document
do i need to add the button to tab one? because i have more than one button
<Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:text="Buy"  />

Comment: Add your xml code to your question, so everyone can see it. Also, that means that you have defined your button. Now you need to into your code and implement the button you defined in your xml. Then in your code, you will need to add the onClick Listener to your button and proivde the implementation for switching between tabs.

Comment: i have added it to the question for everyone to see

Comment: Just added a link to another question on SO that is very similar to the one you are asking. Check it out.

Comment: Posted the stuff regarding your button problem.

Comment: i have one error - getTabHost().setCurrentTabByTag("TAB2"); the setCurrentTabbyTag has an error any idea what has to be done now?

Comment: Do you have another tab created that is tagged as "TAB2"? If not, that is most likely your problem.

Comment: is there anyway i can send someone my project, because i have been working on this for while and the buttons still do not seem to be working

Comment: Not your project, but you could possibly post your code in your above main post and people can take a look at it. All xml files and java files.

Comment: I do not see anything new in the original question.

Comment: super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
TextView textview = new TextView(this); 
textview.setText("This is Tab1"); 
setContentView(R.layout.main); 

Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1); 
button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 
public void onClick(View v) { // Perform action on click 
{ if (v.getId() == R.id.button1) 
{ setContentView(R.layout.tab3); 
; 

} }  } }); }}

this is my new java file, however i still get the same error where the file has to close on my emulator

Comment: Can you place that information in your original post, this way it is much easier to read. Just keep appending it to your original question.

Comment: I see three extra `}`. You may want to try removing them and seeing what happens. There is an extra one after you start your `public void onClick()` and 2 extra at the very end of your code snippet. May not be the problem, but try that and see what happens. (This may be because you pasted the code wrong... but i am assuming you pasted correctly)

Comment: i tried removing them, nothing changed..i still received a message saying unexpected error on my emulator

Comment: Can you post your logcat information in the OP please. This will be greatly helpful. Thanks

Comment: You are doing the "switching to new tab" part wrong inside your `onClick()` method. I posted exactly how to do it. Take a look at the link to the examples i have given you and take a look at the example i posted. Make sure that you have actually defined and implemented the tab you are trying to switch to.

Comment: i was told that words like Exception help you find the problem in your logcat file, here are the exception words
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Tab3

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method tab3(View) in the activity

Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception

Comment: if you can show me the links one more time that will be very helpful

Comment: o.O ... The links are still in the answer i gave you.

Comment: ive been trying to fix the problem, but havent had any luck, do you know how to get it working?

Comment: Well from what i have heard from your questions and responses asked here, i honestly think you need to start with something much easier than what you are attempting. Maybe try to get some more trivial things working in android and then move onto something a little more complicated. Your understanding of java and android currently seems very very trivial... I would suggest reading more and trying some stuff from the API website. Besides writing the code for you, i believe that we have done a very good job helping you so far. The rest is up to you. Sorry, and good luck.

Answer (score 3):

When you create your tabs you give them a tag, let's store one such tag in the variable TAB_1. So in your `onClick()` method, you select that tab by:

```
getTabHost().setCurrentTabByTag(TAB_1);
```

Or, as midoalageb wrote, by index:

```
getTabHost().setCurrentTab(index);
```

Comment: sorry im still confused, what do you mean?

Comment: I assume from your code that you have created a button and want to know what to put in the `onClick()` method. If you have a TabActivity, then you get your TabHost (the object controlling your tabs) with the method `getTabHost()`. If you do not have a TabActivity you should have your TabHost as a member variable. On your TabHost object you then execute either of the two methods.

If this is not your problem, please be more specific about what is not working for you.

Comment: regarding the button, all i have done is create the button in the xml document, nothing has been  linked this is the code i have  <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:text="Buy"  />

Comment: There is a very nice resource on how to make buttons here: [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html). You need to pass R.id.imageButton1 to your `findViewById()` method.

Comment: this is the code in my tab1


public class Tab1 extends Activity { 
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
         TextView textview = new TextView(this); 
         textview.setText("This is Tab1"); 
         setContentView(textview); 
     }
 }


would i add the code in the class overview to that or completely change it?

Comment: Post that type of stuff in your question, please. It is much easier to read outside of the comments. Just let people know in comments that you have updated your original post.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an explanation of [Tab example](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html) :

Create a master Activity:

```
public class HelloTabWidget extends TabActivity
```

And create an Activity for each Tab:

```
public class ArtistsActivity extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        TextView textview = new TextView(this);
        textview.setText("This is the Artists tab");
        setContentView(textview); // you replace this with your layout for each view
    }
}
```

In the master Activity (HelloTabWidget), initiate a TabHost:

```
TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
```

And add TabSpecs for each Tab you have:

```
intent = new Intent().setClass(this, ArtistsActivity.class);
// Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("artists").setIndicator("Artists",
                  res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_artists))
              .setContent(intent);
tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

Select which Tab you need to be the default one:

```
tabHost.setCurrentTab(int index);
```

And finally your Button's onClickListener should be set in the Activity of the Tab containing the Button to:

```
intent = new Intent().setClass(this, ArtistsActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

This Button should be present in all Tabs if you want it to switch between them.

Comment: It switches to the tab specified in the index! If that is not what you need to do, please clarify.

Comment: i have that code in my xml however i have not added anything into my tab1 java file..  i have more than one button so what isit i should do?

 <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:text="Buy"  />

Comment: So where are the Tabs you need to switch between? Check this [link](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html) on how to create tabs.

Comment: I have already created 3 tabs, the xml code is an example of one of the buttons i have in my tab1 xml document, i want it to link to my tab 2 but i dont know how to do that

Comment: Now it is clear :) If you check my link above, each tab is preferred to have a separate Activity and layout, so simply let your button fire an Intent to launch the Tab's relevant Activity and in this new activity, setContentView to the relavent layout.

Comment: i know i might be a pain, but i really do not understand what it is i have to do :S

Comment: I edited my answer to explain the android example and at the end shown what you need to do to let  the button switch between them

Comment: sorry but what you have given doesnt do anything on my code :s