# How to change tabs in Android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-tabhost

I have three tabs that each has its own Activity. The tabs are as follows:

```
Home [HomeActivity]
Search [SearchActivity]
Account [AccountActivity]
```

I have a Main Activity which handles the main TabHost object and this is its content:

```
public TabHost tabHost;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
tabHost = getTabHost();      

tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("Home").setContent(new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class)));

tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator("Search").setContent(new Intent(this, SearchActivity.class).putExtra("callX", true)));
tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab3").setIndicator("Account").setContent(new Intent(this, AccountActivity.class)));
tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
}
```

Now I have a button in Search tab which I need when it is clicked, no matter what, the Home tab should activate. I guess I should somehow call the `setCurrentTab()` method on `tabHost` object but I don't how to access it inside the `SearchActivity` class?
I probably should use `Intent` for that which I have no idea how to use.

Comment: The answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541802/android-switch-tabs-from-within-an-activity-within-a-tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set a method to my main class, which extends TabActivity let's call it "MainActivity"

```
public TabHost getMyTabHost() { 
return tabHost; 
}
```

Then add my tab activity class;

```
MainActivity ta = (MainActivity) this.getParent();
TabHost th = ta.getMyTabHost();
th.setCurrentTab(0);
```

or follow a better aproach [at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541802/android-switch-tabs-from-within-an-activity-within-a-tab/3031178#3031178)