# Android - switch between tabs within activity, get index of tab

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I'm trying to make an activity in a tabHost.
I want to be able to press a button in activity A, thats in tab tA and go to tab tB.
i've found this solution:
[Android - Switch Tabs from within an Activity within a tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541802/android-switch-tabs-from-within-an-activity-within-a-tab)

but I can't figure out how to find the "indexOfTabToSwitch"
How do I get this index?

Comment: You will have to give the index with it. If you want to go to tB and it is on the second position.. You will use `indexOfTabToSwitch(1);`

Comment: this didn't seem to work at first, but i think the problem is because i'm using another Thread to process some other data, and when this is done, it should switch the tab

Comment: yep, it was the thread problem, tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to give the index with it. If you want to go to tB and it is on the second position.. You will use indexOfTabToSwitch(1);