# Switch between tabs programmatically

Tags: android

hey guys currently i have TabHost implemented with 3 tabs each containing separate activity.

Each activity has Spinner view. I want to do Tab switching automatically i.e. when I select

first spinner then next tab should get called automatically. How can I do this?

Comment: See this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541802/android-switch-tabs-from-within-an-activity-within-a-tab

Answer (score 1):

use [TabHost.setCurrentTab](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html#setCurrentTab%28int%29) method. remember that the tab index starts from 0. for example to switch to the second tab use

```
getTabHost().setCurrentTab(1);
```